# zooming and scrolling of image in android

Tags: android

how to zoom and scroll image in android

Comment: Make ur question clear.. Dont just specify this..

Answer (score 1):

There is no default widget for this. SonyEricsson wrote a great series of 4 tutorials on this topic:

http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/

http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/26/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-2/

http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/06/09/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-3/

http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/07/07/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-4/